# Javascript: Sorting user input chronologically

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hopefully, I am not over thinking this. How should I approach sorting user input chronologically, with the oldest movie being displayed first in a newly sorted list?

example:
1980 - The Empire Strikes back
1996 - Independence Day 
1997 - Titanic

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        Year: <br>
        <input id="year" type="text"><br>
        Movie:<br>
        <input id="mName" name="MovieName" type="text"><br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <button onclick="myFunction(list)" type="submit">Submit</button>

    <div id="container">
        <ul id="list">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function myFunction(list){
    var text = "";
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        text +=  inputs[i].value;
    }


    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(text);
    li.appendChild(node);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: you dont have any array then u do soting becz in your html there is only a single html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Update the `DOM` after every insertion of the `li` Element.

- Instead of inserting `year` and `name` as plain text, wrap it in `span` to be access using `DOM-api(querySelector/All)`
- Use [**`Array.from`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create new `Array instance` from an `array-like` or `iterable object`
- Sort the collection using [**`Array#sort`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- Append the `sorted` array to the `parent UL` element in [**`Array#forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop

```js
function myFunction(list) {
  var text = "";
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    text += '<span>' + inputs[i].value + '</span>';
  }
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  var liElemens = document.querySelectorAll('#container #list li');
  liElemens = Array.from(liElemens);
  liElemens.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aSpan = +a.children[0].textContent;
    var bSpan = +b.children[0].textContent;
    return aSpan > bSpan;
  });
  var parent = document.querySelector('#list');
  while (parent.hasChildNodes()) {
    parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
  }
  liElemens.forEach(function(elem) {
    parent.appendChild(elem);
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  Year:
  <br>
  <input id="year" type="text">
  <br>Movie:
  <br>
  <input id="mName" name="MovieName" type="text">
  <br>
</form>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction(list)" type="submit">Submit</button>

<div id="container">
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a much better answer then what I was giving you.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the javascript library UnderscoreJS.

This is most likely the approach I would use.  I would most likely order my javascript in an object, and then sort the items in that object.  [Here is a great blog article](http://janetriley.net/2014/12/sort-on-multiple-keys-with-underscores-sortby.html) which talks all about it.

Of course, you could probably do this with simple arrays, but why not use the full object literal capabilities of javascript?

Here is an example on how to sort using underscore:

```js
let list = [
  {year: "2004", title: "Superman IV"},
  {year: "1974", title: "Superman"},
  {year: "1994", title: "MythBusters"},
  {year: "1984", title: "Ghostbusters"},
];

console.log("Unsorted List");
console.log(list);

// First by Title, then by Year
let sorted = _.sortBy(list, 'year');

console.log("Sorted List");
console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a data structure for the elements already in your list. Then you need to evaluate those extant elements in the list to determine where to insert the new element.

One idea is to just use an array internally to hold the entries of the list. Another idea is to sequentially check `li` DOM elements for the year they contain.

If you choose to actually use the native `li` DOM elements as your primary data structure, you may want to find a sorting algorithm to use.

The advantage of using a built-in array is that you can use the browser's native sort function which may be more efficient than a naive linear search method. However, this difference likely won't be noticeable unless you have a really big list.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arraylist = [];

function myFunction(list) {
  var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
  var mName = document.getElementById("mName").value;
  var obj = {};
  obj.year = parseInt(year);
  obj.mName = mName;
  arraylist.push(obj);
  var sortedAsc = _.sortBy(arraylist, 'year');
  $('#list').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedAsc.length; i++) {
    console.log('-----------')
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var node = document.createTextNode(sortedAsc[i].year + " " + sortedAsc[i].mName);
    li.appendChild(node);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

for reference https://plnkr.co/edit/mi3rtENJWQlzipfsO6Ur?p=preview

Comment: What's with the totally random indenting? With modern editors you would almost have to go out of your way to make it do that.

Comment: sorry what do u mean @EvanTrimboli

Comment: @gayathri, Evan was talking about code formatting..I did that for you ;)

Comment: It's like that in the plnkr as well. I'm curious how you managed to end up in that state.

Answer (score 0):

Counting sort would be good here as year will mostly range from 1900 to 2016 (Make it 2100 , if you don't want your code to break at any upcoming year). It can sort in O(n) time.

Google Counting sort. You will find various implementations.